# Error scaffolding identity in blazor webassembly app

Tags: asp.net, blazor, webassembly

I am building a webassembly project in Razor using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.9.4) and whenever I try to scaffold the identity I get an error saying that a package restore did not work, and everything is rolled back.

My question is twofold:

1. How do I solve this error?
2. Are there any alternatives to the scaffolding of the identity?

Grtz,

Iede Snoek

Answer (score 5):

There is an  [offical page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#standalone-or-hosted-blazor-webassembly-apps) about this but I found it a little confusing. The Blazor WebAssembly UI is not supported, that makes sense. But the Hosted variation should be just like a Blazor Server project. I think that is what is being said there and that makes sense.

But whewn I gave it a try I got the same error as you did, with packages getting rolled back. And no info on what  packages.

So I gave Blazor Server a go, and I kept a watch on the changes. The scaffolding worked and it downgraded some packages from 5.0.5 to 5.0.4 .

After editing the MyProject.Server.csproj the same way scaffolding worked like a charm. The "Manage Packages" UI did not work and I did have to Clean the solution first.

The altered parts of my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

   ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server"
              Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"
              Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
     ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore"
         Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore"
         Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI"
         Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer"
         Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
         Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"
         Version="5.0.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>        
  </ItemGroup>        
</Project>
```

The small version steps make me think this is a very temporary problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it solved my poroblem

Comment: This set me on the right path. I made similar changes (downgrading from 5.0.7) and was able to add scaffolding. Thanks.